# QGIS Python Plugin: Install Python depencies

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

The QGIS Docs clearly says Plugin developers can add a comma separated list of python dependencies that should be installed

```
; Since QGIS 3.8, a comma separated list of plugins to be installed
; (or upgraded) can be specified.
; The example below will try to install (or upgrade) "MyOtherPlugin" version 1.12
; and any version of "YetAnotherPlugin".
; Both "MyOtherPlugin" and "YetAnotherPlugin" names come from their own metadata's
; name field
plugin_dependencies=MyOtherPlugin==1.12,YetAnotherPlugin
```

https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html#metadata-txt

Doing so

```
plugin_dependencies=OSMPythonTools
```

and installing that Plugin as zip fails with following Dialog.

[image]

I'd guess that OSMPythonTools is installed from pypi. But it is not.

How Do I correclty use python dependencies that should be installed via pypi is my Python Qgis Plugin?

Comment: The docs clearly say that you can add "a comma separated list of **plugins** to be installed". Not python packages. Plugin dependencies will be installed from https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins.  You could either ship the python packages you need with the plugin or provide instructions to the user that they need to install the dependencies themselves.

Comment: @user2856 oh yes! Sorry, I was to fast, of course this targets plugins. With  "provide instructions to the user that they need to install the dependencies themselves" you mean a user could / should install dependencies via pip, right?

Comment: That depends how the user has installed QGIS (e.g OSGeo4W, FlatPak, Deb, AUR, Conda) and whether the python package dependencies are better installed through the same method.

Comment: Thanks again @user2856 but this smells llike bad user experience. I will get my hands dirty and try to write it myself ...